# PayPal web error: We're sorry, but we couldn't complete your purchase using the funding source you selected

Tags: paypal

I created an account in PayPal and integrated with PHP in live mode. But when I enter my card details and submit then error message found.

> We're sorry, but we couldn't complete your purchase using the funding source you selected. Please add a debit or credit card.

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypalUrl; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
                <div class="panel price panel-red">
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalId; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="It Solution Stuff">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/paypal/cancel.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/paypal/success.php">  
                        
                    <div class="panel-heading  text-center">
                    <h3>PRO PLAN</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$20 / month</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Some variables used in redirection are:

```
<?php
 $paypalUrl='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
 $paypalId='xxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx';
 ?>
```

Comment: @Filburt Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue for Stackoverflow. There is no technical problem, and certainly no programming problem.

The issue is in the title: "We couldn't complete your purchase using the funding source you selected.", and the solution follows in the quoted message: "Please add a debit or credit card."

This is a normal business exception. When a user sees this message, they need to pay with a different payment method, such as a different card.